# drupal 6: schema api to specify exact size of int data type

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-schema

Using the Drupal 6 schema API, how do you specify the EXACT size of an int data type? For example, I can do the below query in MySQL:

```
create table test (foo int(11) unsigned not null);
```

The drupal 6 schema API only gives me these fixed sizes options of: tiny, small, normal, medium, big.

http://drupal.org/node/159605

I want to create an 'int' data type with a size of 11, to match up with the default drupal 'users' table in the 'created' field.

Comment: Good question. I don't think the Schema API, at least in D6, allows that much specificity. But the "created" field in the users table is declared without a "size", so I take it int(11) is the default size.

Comment: unfortunately the default created size is int(10) - 'normal'. This is why I am puzzled as to why they get to 11 but they don't let us create int(11). I need the int(11) because I am storing UNIX seconds, just like they do for the 'users' table.  I could do a size of 'big', and that would give me int(20).  Just seems like overkill. Any other way?

Comment: Looks like I found a way to get it to 11! You CANNOT set your field to be 'unsigned' => 'true'. If you do that, then it auto-defaults to int(10). But if you leave it out, or set it to 'unsigned' => 'false', then it will give you int(11)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found a way to get it to 11! You CANNOT set your field to be 'unsigned' => 'true'. If you do that, then it auto-defaults to int(10). But if you leave it out, or set it to 'unsigned' => 'false', then it will give you int(11)!